# Unable to import `login_user` from flask-security-too

Tags: python, pip, python-module, flask-security

I am trying to use flask_login from the flask-security-too package, but I cannot seem to import it.

[Looking at the documentation](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_security.login_user), the function does not seem to be deprecated or anything.

I tried different arrangements of package and sub-package to import it, but no luck

```
>>> import flask_security
>>> from flask_security.utils import login_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_security.utils'
>>> from flask_security import login_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'login_user' from 'flask_security' (unknown location)
>>> from flask_security import utils
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils' from 'flask_security' (unknown location)
>>> flask_security.login_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'flask_security' has no attribute 'login_user'
```

And so that you can see what I have installed, here is the output of `pip list`:

```
Package             Version
------------------- ------------
Babel               2.13.1
bcrypt              4.0.1
blinker             1.6.3
boto3               1.28.75
botocore            1.31.75
cffi                1.16.0
click               8.1.7
cryptography        41.0.5
dnspython           2.4.2
email-validator     2.1.0.post1
Flask               3.0.0
Flask-Assets        2.1.0
flask-babel         4.0.0
Flask-BabelEx       0.9.4
Flask-Login         0.6.3
Flask-Mail          0.9.1
Flask-MDE           1.2.1
Flask-Principal     0.4.0
Flask-Security-Too  5.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy    3.1.1
Flask-Table         0.5.0
Flask-WTF           1.2.1
greenlet            3.0.1
gunicorn            21.2.0
idna                3.4
importlib-metadata  6.8.0
importlib-resources 6.1.0
itsdangerous        2.1.2
Jinja2              3.1.2
jmespath            1.0.1
markup              0.2
MarkupSafe          2.1.3
numpy               1.26.1
packaging           23.2
pandas              2.1.2
paramiko            3.3.1
passlib             1.7.4
pip                 23.3.1
psycopg2-binary     2.9.9
pycparser           2.21
PyNaCl              1.5.0
python-dateutil     2.8.2
python-decouple     3.8
python-dotenv       1.0.0
pytz                2023.3.post1
s3transfer          0.7.0
setuptools          53.0.0
six                 1.16.0
speaklater          1.3
SQLAlchemy          2.0.22
sqlalchemy-json     0.7.0
typing_extensions   4.8.0
tzdata              2023.3
urllib3             1.26.18
webassets           2.0
Werkzeug            3.0.1
WTForms             3.1.1
zipp                3.17.0
```

Am I missing something super obvious, or has something changed? I'm certain I have previously just done `from flask_security import login_user` without issue.

Edit: information requested by @john_gordon:

```
NameError: name 'flask_security' is not defined
>>> import flask_security
>>> print(flask_security.__file__)
None
>>> print(dir(flask_security))
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

```
>>> print(flask_security.__path__)
_NamespacePath(['/home/datman/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask_security', '/home/datman/flask_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_security'])
```

```
✗ pip show Flask-Security-Too
Name: Flask-Security-Too
Version: 5.3.2
Summary: Quickly add security features to your Flask application.
Home-page: 
Author: Matt Wright
Author-email: Chris Wagner <jwag.wagner+github@gmail.com>
License: 
Location: /home/datman/flask_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: email-validator, Flask, Flask-Login, Flask-Principal, Flask-WTF, importlib-resources, markupsafe, passlib, wtforms
Required-by:
```

Edit: Installed on a totally fresh venv with nothing else, I am able to import as expected. I will install my requirements one-by-one and see if and when the problem re-emerges.

Edit: So I have reinstalled all my packages and all seems well. The only thing I can think of is that maybe when I initially installed packages from `requirements.txt` it caused different versions of packages to be pulled in and thus I ended up with a dependency issue. I had manually uninstalled `flask-security` and replaced it with `flask-security-too`, maybe that caused problems that pip was not able to detect/resolve.

Comment: Did you create your own local python file named `flask_security.py` ?

Comment: No, is that something I am supposed to do?

Comment: No, you're **not** supposed to do that.  But if you had, it would explain the problem.

Comment: Show us the output of these print statements `print(flask_security.__file__)` and `print(dir(flask_security))`

Comment: @JohnGordon I have added that output to the question.

Comment: Hmm.  How about `print(flask_security.__path__)`

Comment: It's right in the venv site packages folder where it should be (right?). Output also added to question.

Comment: Strange.  Can you show the output of this command `pip show Flask-Security-Too`

Comment: Nothing looks amiss there either (see question). Maybe I somehow broke my environment, I will try starting with a fresh one and installing things as needed instead of using the `requirements.txt` I have been using.

Comment: I recall hearing about a deprecation issue with flask v2 and flask-login. Are you using flask V2? Or V1?

Comment: @YaakovBressler I did do some uninstalling and installing new package versions (although not of Flask specifically), so you might be correct. In any case, I solved it by rebuilding my venv from scratch.