# What causes an ImportError to report "(unknown location)"?

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77411571/494134), there is this import error:

```
>>> from flask_security import login_user
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'login_user' from 'flask_security' (unknown location)
```

What causes the "(unknown location)" message?

Prior to seeing this, I had a kind of vague assumption that it meant the module was built in to python itself, like `sys`, and so it did not have any external file at all.

But that is clearly not the case in the linked question.

Answer (score 3):

`(unknown location)` appears in an `ImportError` whenever the module's [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#file__) attribute is not set (or is set to something other than a string).

This can be the case for a variety of reasons:

1. C modules that are statically<sup>1</sup> linked to the Python interpreter leave `__file__` unset. This includes modules like `sys` as mentioned in the question.
2. For modules representing [namespace packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/), [`__file__` will be set to `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec.origin).
3. If the module was created using [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType), `__file__` won't be set.
4. When a module is imported using a [custom loader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.Loader) from [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html), whether `__file__` is set depends on the implementation of the loader.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Dynamically loaded extension modules will set `__file__` to the path of the shared library.</sup>

The following produces an `(unknown location)` import error by  directly creating a module with `types.ModuleType`. Note that we can set the module's `__file__` attribute at any point to change how the error message is displayed.

```
import sys
import types

sys.modules["foo"] = types.ModuleType("foo", "Foo module")

# Import with no __file__ set
>>> from foo import bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'foo' (unknown location)

# Set __file__ to a dummy value
>>> sys.modules["foo"].__file__ = "/fake/path/to/foo.py"
>>> from foo import bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'foo' (/fake/path/to/foo.py)
```

Similarly, we can see the same `(unknown location)` behavior when using a custom loader that does not set the module's `__file__` attribute:

```
import importlib.abc

class SimpleLoader(importlib.abc.Loader):
    def create_module(self, spec):
        return None

    def exec_module(self, module):
        pass


loader = SimpleLoader()
loader.load_module("foo")

>>> from foo import bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'foo' (unknown location)
```

If instead the custom loader sets `__file__` to some value, we'll set that value instead of `(unknown location)`:

```
import importlib.abc


class SpoofLoader(importlib.abc.Loader):
    def create_module(self, spec):
        return None

    def exec_module(self, module):
        module.__file__ = "spoofed location"


loader = SpoofLoader()
loader.load_module("foo")

>>> from foo import bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ImportError: cannot import name 'bar' from 'foo' (spoofed location)
```

Answer (score 3):

The most likely scenario is there is a [PEP 420](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/) *namespace package* (usually just an empty folder):

```
$ mkdir example_dir
$ python3 -c 'from example_dir import wat'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'wat' from 'example_dir' (unknown location)
```

this is almost certainly the cause of the problem in the linked question as well